# DB2 Java user defined function

Tags: java, function, db2

I'm trying to write a Java function for my DB2 database.
When my class is in SQLLIB/Function all is working great.
Now i need to change the path of the class to another location for client deployment.
I can't seem to make it work.

Please Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to register your jar file with the database with 'SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR'.

CALL SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR('file:/home/db2inst/classes/Proc.jar' , 'myproc_jar', 0)

see:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/writeudf.htm